# Questions regarding Kubernetes storage

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I have two questions regarding K8s storage:

1. Can I set up an NFS server on one of the worker nodes in a bare-metal cluster?
2. I am running different versions of our application which consists of different components on different namespaces. If I want to use StorageOS do I need to install one StorageOS per namespace?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.  Check out [this example](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-volumes-example-nfs-persistent-volume.html) for a nice tutorial to get started.
2. Per the StorageOS [documentation](https://docs.storageos.com/docs/concepts/namespaces) you shouldn't even have to worry about this.  Just let StorageOS handle the namespaces for you with one StorageOS install.